# How to add far-future expires headers to minified cssfiles/scripts?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, minify

how to i add add far-future expires headers to minified cssfiles/scripts? I am using minify to combine css files and javascripts files, but the minified versions don't have a far-future expiration date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Apache, then this sort of thing is the way to go.  There are several different ways to do it depending on the modules installed; some make it easier than others.  I recommend the `expires` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)) and `headers` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)) modules (they're both required for the example below, but you can pull it off with only `headers` if you really want).

```
<LocationMatch "/js/(.*)\.js">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
</LocationMatch>
```

This example matches all files in /js/ that end with a .js extension and set an expiry time of 10 years into the future relative to the time the file is accessed.  It also explicitly sets Cache-Control to be public; we run everything [over SSL](http://blog.pluron.com/2008/07/why-you-should.html), so it might not be necessary otherwise, but it won't hurt you either way.

This example can easily be extended to match your CSS locations and files as well; just copy, paste and change the LocationMatch.

There are plenty of sites that will give you a full rundown on this; check out this one, "[Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)", which seems to cover it all.

Comment: that gave me an Internal Server Error, i use apache

Comment: @jc, have you enabled the `expires` and `headers` modules for apache?

Answer (score 3):

/min/README.txt has [documentation for sending far-future expires headers](http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/branches/2.1.4/min/README.txt?r=438#110).

> Minify can send far-future (one year) Expires headers. To enable this you must
>   add a number to the querystring (e.g. `/min/?g=js&1234` or `/min/f=file.js&1234`) 
>   and alter it whenever a source file is changed. If you have a build process you 
>   can use a build/source control revision number.
>
> You can alternately use the utility function Minify_getUri() to get a "versioned"
>   Minify URI for use in your HTML.

Comment: I'm a little confused by how this works. My understanding is that the http spec calls for browsers to always get a fresh copy of any request with a query string. Doesn't this defeat far-future caches? Or is Minify overriding this through the use of header directives?

Comment: `Cache-Control: max-age=#` allows resources w/ querystring to be cached. There's a RewriteRule in the .htaccess so "?" isn't necessary in the URL, but this is for certain older proxy caches.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what web server you are using.  It can't be done by modifying the CSS or script files themselves, though.